# Upload textarea's contents as formdata?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm curious what the best way to upload (via jquery AJAX) a decent amount of text from a `<textarea></textarea>` element... I'm trying to do this, but my server is only getting around 19 lines of text when the textarea contains much more than that... Any tips would be appreciated. I don't even know what the limits of length are on an upload of this nature.

```
var data = new FormData();
    var cssData = $("#custom-css-text").val();
    data.append("custom_css", cssData);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MYENDPOINT',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(response){
            // do stuff

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try passing cssData into data. data : { text : cssData }

Comment: is your DB type set to text instead of varchar(x)  ?

Comment: There are some limits imposed on the size of a POST request, but they're usually a lot larger than 19 lines. What language are you using on the server side? PHP will limit the amount of text it reads from a post request via the `post_max_size` variable in your php.ini. If you're using an Apache web server, the size of a post request can be limited by the LimitRequestBody configuration directive.

Comment: It appears my database was truncating it because of the type for some reason. We've changed it to a blob and It seems to be returning the proper amount of data.

Comment: We're using a 4D Database. Thanks for the tips/responses here.